# Class Not Found Exception after using IWorkspaceRunnable

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, classnotfoundexception

I get the Class Not Found Exception after Exporting the plugin I'm developing as a Deployable Feature.

Normally I place the generated Jar in the dropins folder and I can use it. But after adding what seemed the proper way of saving changes to a resource using `IWorkspaceRunnable` I started getting the not Class Def Exception when I try to run the deployed plugin. (Note the plugin runs fine when testing it without deploying, aka Run as Eclipse Application)

```
    IWorkspaceRunnable saveTask = new IWorkspaceRunnable() {

        @Override
        public void run(IProgressMonitor monitor) throws CoreException {
            if (fileName != null) try {
                myEditor.save(new File(fileName));
                firePropertyChange(PROP_DIRTY);
                ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().refreshLocal(IResource.DEPTH_INFINITE, null);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error while saving: \n"+e.toString());
            }
        }
    };
    try {
        ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().run(saveTask, null);
    } catch (CoreException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error while saving: \n"+e.toString());
    }
```

Any idea how to get this working?

`org.eclipse.core.resources`, which holds `IWorkspaceRunnable`, is already present in my "Plug-in dependencies" folder. I think it got there automatically at some point. Is there somewhere else I should put/reference that particular jar? I haven't done anything else for the other classes I'm using from org.eclipse.*.

EDIT: Here is the MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: MyPlugin
Bundle-SymbolicName: MyPlugin;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.1
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui,org.eclipse.core.runtime,org.eclipse.ui
 ,org.eclipse.core.runtime,org.eclipse.jface.text,org.eclipse.ui.edito
 rs,org.eclipse.ui.ide,org.eclipse.core.resources;visibility:=reexport
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
Bundle-Vendor: myVendor
Bundle-ClassPath: /usr/share/eclipse/plugins/,.
```

How I'm deploying the plugin:

I'm placing the .jar in /home//.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_/dropins/, with version being 4.2.0_1543616141. This may not be the proper way to deploy it, but it worked before adding references to `org.eclipse.core.resources`.

I'm interested in creating a standalone-ish plugin that can be dropped in the dropins folder and just run.

Comment: Can you update the question with what your plugin MANIFEST.MF looks like?

Comment: @PaulWebster I added MANIFEST.MF, anything unusual there?

Comment: You can't have /usr/share/eclipse/plugins in your bundle classpath, only `.` or jars contained within your plugin.  Anything from the plugins will be available from your RCP application.

Comment: Yeah, I added that one in a desperate attempt to get it working, but I still have the same CNFE problem. Do you spot any other thing in the manifest?

Comment: This will be my first plugin, so maybe I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Are you deploying this into an Eclipse SDK?  Or an RCP app?

Comment: I'm placing the `.jar` in `/home/<username>/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_<version>/dropins/`, with version being `4.2.0_1543616141`. This is maybe not the proper way to deploy it, but it worked before adding references to `org.eclipse.core.resources`. I'm interested in creating a more standalone-ish plugin that can be dropped in the dropins folder and just run.

Comment: Can you add a pastebin or gist with anything in the log file? <workspace>/.metadata/.log

Comment: I don't have such file, my metadata folder contains a file called version.ini, containing only one line: "org.eclipse.core.runtime=1"
After trying to reproduce the CNFE by adding references to the problematic classes again, it worked fine... I'll try to reproduce the CNFE again and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

`ClassNotFoundException` indicates that something is missing on the classpath. Maybe you are missing a library in the classpath.

> As the name suggests classNotFoundException in Java is a subclass of java.lang.Exception and Comes when Java Virtual Machine tries to load a particular class and doesn't found the requested class in classpath.